# @Cacheable not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-3

I am using @Cacheable for caching the result of a method at Service layer in Spring 3.2. following method code is used inside service Class:

```
@Cacheable("questions")
public List<ABClassObject> getSecutityQuestionsList(){
 List<ABClassObject> list = new ArrayList<ABClassObject>();
  ----------------
 list = ----[DAO call]

return list;

}
```

xml Configuration

```
    <cache:annotation-driven />

  <!-- Generic cache manager based on the JDK ConcurrentMap -->
      <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
          <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="questions" />
          </set>
        </property>
      </bean>
```

Can't use EhCache because of using jdk 1.6.
By using the above code pattern i am unable to cache the List result.DAO is called all the time when i call the above method.
So, Suggest me whats wrong with the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some things you should check:

1. The class of getSecutityQuestionsList method is a spring bean, i.e, you don´t use a new operator anyway.
2. The method getSecutityQuestionsList is called from another bean
3. In your xml configuration put a  context:component-scan base-package="xxxxx"
4. Put a break point inside your method. In the stack trace you should see some spring proxy stuff. When you call this method of your service, you should actually be calling a spring proxy.